# How can I transform all row nested rows back into normal rows bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that look like this:

```
Row id  edad    nombre     sector          contacto.telefono    contacto.correo 
1   275  18   dozolme      El Golf         5555555          xxxxx@xxxxxx.com
                                           123456789        yyyyy@yyyyy.com
                                           35161631
```

How can I get it back to this?

```
Row id  edad    nombre     sector          telefono             correo  
1   275  18   dozolme      El Golf         5555555          xxxxx@xxxxxx.com
2   275  18   dozolme      El Golf         123456789        yyyyy@yyyyy.com
3   275  18   dozolme      El Golf         35161631         null --> ? maybe null?
```

The schema is:

```
id                  INTEGER NULLABLE    
edad                INTEGER NULLABLE    
nombre              STRING  NULLABLE    
sector              STRING  NULLABLE    
contacto            RECORD  REPEATED    
contacto.telefono   STRING  REPEATED    
contacto.correo     STRING  REPEATED
```

EDIT

This is how I'm getting the output now [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * except(contacto, telefono, correo),
  telefono, correo
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(contacto), 
unnest(telefono) as telefono with offset
join unnest(correo) as correo with offset
using(offset)
```

Comment: Still getting those empty spaces :(. The row 1 does not transform into 3 different rows

Comment: i just tried with sample data from your question - and I see no empty spaces!!! - please double check and/or clarify your problem

Comment: Added a photo with the output of the query

Comment: try updated version - I realized that telefono, correo are also repeated so adjusted code respectively

Comment: THANK YOU!! This worked! can you explain me a little bit why and how? Or point me in the direction to where I can learn more about this. Sometimes I feel that I'm weak in SQL.

Comment: sure. so first unnest just flattens `contacto` array. then `telefono` and `correo` arrays being also flattened and their elements joined on their positions in those arrays. and then - original `contacto, telefono, correo` arrays being excluded from output via `except` . hope this helps. consider voting up the answer

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato . . . I think this only returns the minimum of the number of telephone numbers and emails.  So, if you have 3 phone numbers and 2 emails, you get only 2 phone numbers with this query.

Comment: Gordon is correct. Somehow my assumption was that telephone and email are related to each other. Meantime, Gordon's answer does not work at all and simply fails!!!  :o(

Answer (score 1):

You have a very strange data structure -- an array of contactos with arrays of emails and telephone numbers in them.  Too many repeated fields.

```
select t.* except (contacto, telefono, correo),
       te, co
from t left join
     unnest(t.contacto) c
     on 1=1 left join
     (unnest(c.telefono) te with offset tn full join
      unnest(c.correo) co with offset cn
      on tn = cn
     )
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: Probably because of my lack of experience. Isn't that the "correct way" of storing the contact info of a person? Telephone and email shouldn't be under "contact info"?

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato . . . I doubt the telephone and email are related to each other.  You should just have two arrays, one for telephone numbers and one for emails -- no struct is needed.

Comment: Well...yeah...telephone and email are not related to each other. The only relation is they belong to a particular person, but nothing else. Maybe I have a miss conception about structs and arrays. Could you please recommend me where I can learn all this